# How to display default PopOVer of ios8?

Tags: ios, swift, popup, uipopovercontroller

i am trying to show popover in ios8 using swift as

```
    @IBAction func showPopUP(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let popVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pop")as! PopViewController

        popVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        self.presentViewController(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        var presentationController = UIPopoverPresentationController()
        presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left | UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right
        presentationController.sourceView = popVC.view
        presentationController.sourceRect = popVC.view.frame

    }
}
```

However gives me an error as

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: '-[UIPopoverController init] is not a valid initializer. You
>   must call -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:].'

What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT: 
 i want to show popover as of the default of ios 8

[image]

Here is the link of project on GoogleDrive :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6dTvD1JbkgBM3F6RXhjVGFvZmM&authuser=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well first of all you set the Deleagte of *UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate* to self. then implement this method as

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(PC: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }
```

This tells your iphone forcefully show the VC as popover.

and implement your IBAction same way as

```
 @IBAction func showPopUP(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)            
        let popVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("pop")as! PopViewController            
        popVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        popVC.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        let popOverController = popVC.popoverPresentationController
        popOverController!.sourceView = sender as! UIView
        popOverController!.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        popOverController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
        self.presentViewController(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating a new `UIPopoverPresentayionController` yourself, you should be requesting the controller from your presented controller:

```
var presentationController = popVC.popoverPresentationController
```

Also, when you do:

```
presentationController.sourceView = popVC.view
presentationController.sourceRect = popVC.view.frame
```

you're using the wrong view and frame. The view should be the view that the popover is presented from, not the popover view, and the rect is the area in the source view where the presentation if from (i.e. where the arrow comes from).

Comment: thanks man!!1 but we dont need that () ...and although i changed it why it is not showing as popup?

Comment: ok, I don't really write swift so don't remember the syntax all the time. how does it show?

Comment: just as normal while presenting view controller with animation

Comment: ok..i will provide you the project...look the link on question

Answer (score 0):

You need not to initialise `UIPopoverPresentationController`, you can get reference from `viewcontorller` which you want to present as popover

```
@IBAction func showPopUP(sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let popVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("productcontroller")as! ProductController

    popVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    self.presentViewController(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    var presentationController = popVC.popoverPresentationController  //Here, you can go with
    presentationController!.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left | UIPopoverArrowDirection.Right
    presentationController!.sourceView = popVC.view
    presentationController!.sourceRect = popVC.view.frame

}
```

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: thanks the error is gone..but nextVC doesnot show as popup :(

Comment: @copeME Showing in iPhone or iPad?

Comment: @copeME, [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxiq7GsJqbc2RnpzbmdmRmVtNjQ/view?usp=sharing) is your code with purpose, You can get help from [THIS](http://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html).

Comment: if it can be done using segue..then why not in button action while presenting view controller....thanks for the work..but really i want something like i said